# Qt: deleteLater deletes object only on application close

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qobject

I have a MainWindow which creates, in one of its slots, some other widget, let's call it `A`. Also at some point later on some other slot, that widget should be deleted, so a call `A->deleteLater()`;

But I noticed that destructor for A is only called when the application close.

What can produce such a behaviour? Why is `deleteLater` so delayed?

I'm using Qt 4.8.6. Everything happens in a main thread, and main event loop is running.

Comment: the behavior you describe is abnormal. Did you use a debugger to detect the exact deletion time?

Comment: Yes, I also added a log line in widget destructor. And every time it is called on application close. I'm using OSX. And application is mostly idle.

Comment: Providing a working [code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would significantly improve this question.

Comment: I tried with minimal working example, and everything worked fine. I can't disclose code I'm working on because it's huge and proprietary. I'm looking for some hint, where to look, because deleteLater is definitely called and destructor is called only at application close.

Comment: @agnor Are you overriding the event handler in `A`?  If so, you can create this behavior if you fail to call the `QWidget` event handler when you override.

Comment: @RA. It makes sense, but unfortunately its not the case.  `A` does not override event handler.

Comment: @agnor Is there an event filter on `A`?  Can you post some more details about `A`?